# Yii2 ActiveForm Validation not working with bootstrap modal on first load

Tags: yii2, bootstrap-modal, yii2-basic-app, active-form

> "The ActiveForm validation will not work on the first modal load, BUT
>   the second time, if you don't refresh the page and just close the modal
>   window and load it again."

This happens on even the fresh install of `yii2-app-basic`.

#### What steps will reproduce the problem?

Create a view `views/site/modal.php`  and add the modal code like below with an extra button and `js` code to open the modal window on button click and bind event `shown.bs.modal` to load the view inside the modal content section once modal is shown

```
<?php

use yii\bootstrap\Modal;
use yii\helpers\Html;

Modal::begin([
    'id' => 'contact',
]);
?>

<div class="modal-header">
    <h4>Contact</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">

</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <?php
    echo Html::submitButton('Add Folder Now', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
    ?>

</div>

<?php Modal::end() ;

 echo Html::button('button', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary','id'=>'add-folder-button']);

 $js=<<< js
        $("#add-folder-button").on('click',function(){
            $( '#contact' ).modal( {show:true});
            $( '#contact' ).appendTo("body");
        });

         $( '#contact' ).on( 'shown.bs.modal', function ( event ) {
            // var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
            let modal = $( this );
            modal.find( '.modal-header > h4' ).text( 'Contact Us' );
            modal.find( '.modal-body' ).load( 'contact');
        } );
js;
$this->registerJs($js,\yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

Create an action inside the `SiteController` to load the above view

```
public function actionModal(){
    return $this->render('modal');
}
```

---

Now modify the `actionContact`  inside the `SiteController` like below to be loaded inside the modal window

```
/**
     * Displays contact page.
     *
     * @return Response|string
     */
    public function actionContact()
    {
        $model = new ContactForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->contact(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('contactFormSubmitted');
            return $this->refresh();
        }
        return $this->renderAjax('contact', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

For the view, you can use the default `contact.php` view inside the `views/site` folder just add the below code on top of the view

```
$js=<<< js
        alert("hello");
js;
$this->registerJs($js);
```

#### What is the expected result?

on clicking the button the modal window should load and as soon the view is loaded it should show you the `alert("hello")`, and if I cycle/TAB through the fields it should run the `ActiveForm` client validation.

*Note : i even tried providing `'enableClientValidation'=>true` in the form options.*

#### What do you get instead?

it Does nothing neither it shows the `alert` neither it runs the validation, instead if you close and then click the button again to open the modal window then everything works correctly. The alert is shown and the client validation works. but if you refresh the page again it won't work again until you open the modal window once and close it and open it again.

The above scenario works perfectly in Yii 1.x versions and I have it working I am working on a yii1.x extension to transform it into yii2.x

#### Additional info

```
| Q                | A
| ---------------- | ---
| Yii version      | 2.0.15.1
| PHP version      | 5.6
| Operating system | windows
```

***Note: I added an issue on [GITHUB-yiisoft](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/16867) but it was labeled as a question, although its the most basic setup to open a form inside a modal window and i have used it in the past but currently it isn't working, and this is not a normal behavior either it should work or it should not work at all if Yii does not support it.***

Comment: i think you have to register ActiveForm assets on your main view (no on modal content view)

Comment: Also tried it out and see the same effect. Not sure why the alert and the validation works with the second click. Not a solution: it would be better if the contact form gets inserted into the modal body directly. With the given approach the the form gets unnecessarily loaded each time the modal opens.

Comment: @robsch you mean rather than using ajax to inject the form via `shown.bs.modal` I should render the form inside the `Modal::begin()` and `Modal::end()`? so that it is already populated at the time of page load?

Comment: Exactly. I would copy the content to the body or include it. Might be also not perfect, since if you use it in the nav bar then it would be part of the page with each rendering. But that can be an acceptable overhead. What I don't like with the subsequent loading is also the delay, leaving the modal for a short time empty. I have this somewhere also like that and I don't enjoy it. I think using the Modal with directly placing the conent into the body is the intended way. That way you can even remove any JS code for opening/closing the Modal.

Comment: @robsch hmm, that wont work, i am making a filemanager extension for yii2 which i created earlier for yii1 [demo](https://plugins.idowstech.com/site/demotinymce) and wanted to transform it in yii2 there i am using this extension as a part of tinyMCE editor plugin or a standalone module to be accessed directly, and when accessing this extension directly without using the editor button i need to pass the current directory name as the popup modal is used to open a form to create a new folder and i need the parent folder that i am passing with the request to the view currently.

Comment: if you look into the demo you will find a button on editor with label `IDOWS TinyYii Filemanager` upon clicking it will open a window where you can find a button on top left `Create Folder` which will make the situation more clear why i need to do it